# Simplest solution for uploading images to cloud service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, cloud

What is the simplest way to allow people to upload an image to a cloud server (in a Rails 3 app)? I want to include an "upload image" button in the form, and store the address in my model. I'd also like to be able to constrain the file size.

Comment: If you are planning to use this image as an avatar, check out https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem for rails:

Here is a nice tutorial: [Uploading Files to S3 in Ruby with Paperclip](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3)

Answer (score 6):

I recommend attachinary and the cloudinary service:

https://github.com/assembler/attachinary

It's a huge time saver to not need to mess around with imagemagick.  Cloudinary is an amazing service that resizes images on the fly.  Attachinary comes with great integration to jquery upload widgets too.

Comment: Totally agreed, cloudinary is awesome. We use the carrierwave gem with cloudinary as storage backend, so cloudinary ends up hosting not just our images but all uploaded assets. Details here: http://cloudinary.com/blog/ruby_on_rails_image_uploads_with_carrierwave_and_cloudinary